# linkbutton inside datagrid not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

i have a datagrid,which contains a template field like this

```
               <Columns>

                <asp:BoundColumn HeaderStyle-CssClass="AdminGridHeaderNew" 
                    DataField="orderid" HeaderText="Order Id"></asp:BoundColumn>

                  <asp:TemplateColumn>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkbtndate" runat="server"CommandName="Edit"><%# Eval("orderdate")%></asp:LinkButton>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <HeaderTemplate>
                    Date
                    </HeaderTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateColumn>

            </Columns>
```

i tried to acces  the linkbutton control in code like this

```
    protected void dgdNew_EditCommand(object source, DataGridCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        string Oid = e.Item.Cells[0].Text;
        LinkButton Date = ((LinkButton)e.Item.Cells[1].FindControl("lnkbtndate"));

    }
```

i get the value of Oid(which is not mentioned) because it is in a asp:BoundColumn field,but i didnt get the linkbutton control in Date.can anybody help

Answer (score 1):

you should not be searching in `Cells[1]` try in this way:

```
LinkButton myButton = e.Item.FindControl("lnkbtndate") as LinkButton;

if(myButton != null)
{
  //... here use the myButton as needed...
}
```